# How to reorganize objects by same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have 3 objects

```
[
{name: 3, q: 10, b: 1},
{name: 5, q: 6, b: 2},
{name: 5, q: 7, b: 1}
]
```

I need to group them by name:

```
[
{name: 3: items: [{q:10, b: 1}]},
{name: 5: items: [{q:6, b: 2}, {q:7, b: 1}]},
]
```

maybe there are any delicate solutions with lodash?

Comment: Give us what you have tried so far, and we'll help you fix the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need lodash, you can just use JavaScript

```
const inputArray = [
  {name: 3, q: 10, b: 1},
  {name: 5, q: 6, b: 2},
  {name: 5, q: 7, b: 1}
];
```

using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
function groupItemsByName(array) {
  // create a groups to store your new items
  const groups = {};
  
  //loop through your array
  array.forEach(obj => {
    // destructure each object into name and the rest 
    const { name, ...rest } = obj;
    // if the named group doesnt exist create that name with an empty array
    if (!groups[name]) {
      groups[name] = { name, items: [] };
    }
    // add the items to the named group based on the name
    groups[name].items.push(rest);
  });

  return Object.values(groups);
}

const transformedArray = groupItemsByName(inputArray);
```

using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```
function groupItemsByName(array) {
  //Object.values returns an objects values as an array  
  return Object.values(
    array.reduce((groups, obj) => {
      // destructure as in the forEach method
      const { name, ...rest } = obj;
      // create the groups like in the previous method
      groups[name] = groups[name] || { name, items: [] };
      // push the items to the group based on the name
      groups[name].items.push(rest);
      return groups;
    }, {})
  );
}


const transformedArray = groupItemsByName(inputArray);
```

using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and reduce

```
const transformedArray = Array.from(
  inputArray.reduce((map, obj) => {
    const { name, ...rest } = obj;
    const existing = map.get(name) || { name, items: [] };
    existing.items.push(rest);
    return map.set(name, existing);
  }, new Map()).values()
);
```

output

```
console.log(transformedArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) combined with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Code:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 3, q: 10, b: 1 },
  { name: 5, q: 6, b: 2 },
  { name: 5, q: 7, b: 1 },
]

const groupedData = Object.values(
  data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    const { name, ...rest } = obj
    acc[name] = acc[name] || { name, items: [] }
    acc[name].items.push(rest)
    return acc
  }, {})
)

console.log(groupedData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following simple solution to achieve this.

```
const originalArr = [//This is your original input array
    { name: 3, q: 10, b: 1 },
    { name: 5, q: 6, b: 2 },
    { name: 5, q: 7, b: 1 }
];
let filteredArr = [];
originalArr.forEach(el => {
    const index = filteredArr.findIndex(__el => __el.name == el.name);
    if (index == -1) {//This means the current element does not exists in filtered array
        filteredArr.push({ name: el.name, items: [{ q: el.q, b: el.b }] });
    } else {
        filteredArr[index].items.push({ q: el.q, b: el.b });
    }
});
console.log(filteredArr);//You will get your desired output
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello simply you can use for loop with find function.

i will try to help you Please check below example

```
let mainArr = [
    { name: 3, q: 10, b: 1 },
    { name: 5, q: 6, b: 2 },
    { name: 5, q: 7, b: 1 },
];

let setArr = [];

for (let arr of mainArr) {
    let checkValue = setArr.find((e) => e.name.toString() === arr.name.toString());

    if (!checkValue) {
        setArr.push({ name: arr.name, items: [{ q: arr.q, b: arr.b }] });
    } else {
        checkValue.items.push({ q: arr.q, b: arr.b });
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(setArr, null, 2));

Result: [
    { name: 3, items: [{ q: 10, b: 1 }] },
    {
        name: 5,
        items: [
            { q: 6, b: 2 },
            { q: 7, b: 1 },
        ],
    },
];
```

I hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it using lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const objects = [
  { name: 3, q: 10, b: 1 },
  { name: 5, q: 6, b: 2 },
  { name: 5, q: 7, b: 1 }
];

const groupedObjects = _.groupBy(objects, 'name');
const result = _.map(groupedObjects, (items, name) => ({ name: Number(name), items }));

console.log(result);
```

Output

```
[
  { name: 3, items: [ { q: 10, b: 1 } ] },
  { name: 5, items: [ { q: 6, b: 2 }, { q: 7, b: 1 } ] }
]
```